# How did the French word 'familier' become associated with the concept of Magical Familiars, historically?

Tags: europe, france, etymology, folklore

How did the word 'familier' (French) become associated with the concept of [Magical Familiars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familiar_spirit), historically?

Or do we not know?

[Proof for the concept being from French, first.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95664/42059)

Comment: Can you show that it is in fact from the French, and not from the English word, as in e.g. "familiar spirit"?

Comment: bordering on mythology, not history

Comment: @jamesqf - How about this?: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95664/42059

Comment: @Well, if you want, you could request a move to Mythology.SE...

Comment: More of an etymological question than either mythology or history, but I feel it's ambiguous enough to fit on both stacks.

Comment: I think that @Malandy has scoped this pretty precisely to etymology and history.  [Sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donation_of_Constantine) in the study of history it is vital to know what a word meant at a specific time, and how the use evolved over time.  It is an odd question, but I believe it to be in scope.

Comment: Interesting question. I know that in modern french, familiars in the magical sense is not translated as  un (a) familier, instead they use compagnon (companion). This question is even more interesting because they do use familier to mean a pet, so that link with the translation must of happened before the modern change? or did they translate it to pet? so many good questions.

Comment: @Alexandre: The OED lists the meaning of "a pet" as the first sense of the word, suggesting that the word first entered the English language in that sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED attests several use of the word *familiar* in Chaucer's works from the 1380's, in the usual sense of "*pertaining to personal relations or family*."

However the earliest use attested to in the OED in the sense of a *familiar spirit* is from 1584: **R SCOTT**, *Discovering Witchcraft*, III. xv. 65

> *A flie, otherwise called a divell or familiar*

There is also an attestation of *familiar angel*, in our modern sense of *guardian angel*, dating to 1460.

From this, it seems clear that the word *familiar* entered the English language in its usual sense 100 to 200 years before it gained the additional sense being referred to by OP. Thus it is likely a derivation from the prior English, not the original Old French root.

**Update**: re *flie* in the quote above.

The same quote is referenced by the OED in sense **5** of the meaning of the word *fly", with *flie* as an obsolete spelling of the word:

> **Fly**
>   ...
>   **5**
>   *A familiar, from the notion that a devil was accustomed to appear in the form of a fly*

Comment: What's a "flie"? I get "divell" = "devil"...

Comment: @Malandy: I'm not an expert in Middle English - that's how it is spelled in my copy of the OED. I'm guessing that it is pronounced the same as either the modern word "fly" or "flea". but neither makes sense to me.

Comment: @Malandy: See my update (When in doubt, check the OED again!). It means "fly" as I suspected.

Comment: Geerkins - I guess the idea of demonic flies are related to Beelzebub, Lord of Flies, somehow? [Random thought...]

Comment: So, I guess the logical leap from "something personal" to "servant spirit (in the form of an animal)", would be something like this? : Animals that hang around 'witches' -> evil spirits, and then 'familiars' when assuming that 'familiars' are bonded to witches, and then the sharing senses powers add itself to the definition or something...